# Creating new Azure Mobile App backend never completes; fails to show settings blade

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to create a new mobile app backend following the Wesley McSwain tutorial at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started/. I logged on the the Azure Portal and got thru step 4. The tutorial warns that *"Provisioning a Mobile App backend can take several minutes; the Settings blade for the Mobile App backend is displayed when complete."* I clicked OK in this window [image: AppServicePlan window from the portal].

There is a little spinning widget at the right end of the text box for the App name and it has been over an hour and the "Settings blade" has still failed to display. Never having done this before, I am unclear about what to expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like something simple has gone wrong - your browser lost connectivity with the portal and missed something.  Refresh the page and try again.

Comment: Thanks...perhaps a simple refresh of the page might have worked. Instead, I logged off the portal and then when I logged back onto the portal, the deploy succeeded, allowing me to visit the quick start link and navigate to the next step in the tutorial (connect a database).